# Hibernate JPQL para múltiplos likes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Estou utilizando o hibernate no meu projeto e estou com dúvidas na questão de utilizar múltiplos likes dinâmicos na pesquisa.

Tenho um simples campo na página onde o cliente pode digitar o nome de um usuário, mais necessito que ele possa digitar 2 nomes se necessário para retornar uma lista.

Exemplo: "João" (Até ai ok, dou um simples like no nome joão, e minha namedQuery fica assim:

```
"select c from Cliente c where c.nome like :nome"
```

Mais quando a pessoa digitar 2 nomes, estou separando em uma lista de nomes, se ele digitar "João Diego" estou dando um split e separando em palavras para achar nomes relacionados as 2 palavras obtidas.

Na questão do split tudo ok, mais como ficaria minha JPQL? se eu criar uma com 2 likes, e a pessoa digitar 3 nomes, não iria ficar dinâmico.

Existe alguma forma na JPQL para eu poder dar multiplos likes sem a necessidade de criar uma namedQuery com a qualidade de likes que eu vou fazer?

EDIT:----------

Encontrei uma forma de fazer mais acredito que não seja nem de perto uma forma correta. Gostaria que se alguém avaliasse e pudesse me ajudar.

```
map.clear();
    map.put("cidade", cidade);

    String[] palavras = pesquisa.split(" ");

    if(palavras.length <= 1){
        map.put("pesquisa", "%"+pesquisa+"%");
        anuncios = (List<Anuncio>) daoMaster.listaPorNamedQuery("efetuaPesquisa", map, Anuncio.class);
    }else{
        query = "select a from Anuncio a where a.cidade = :cidade and (a.nome = '%"+palavras[0].toString()+"'";
        for(int i=1;i < palavras.length;i++){
            query += " OR a.nome like '%"+palavras[i].toString()+"%'";
        }
        for(int i=0;i < palavras.length;i++){
            query += " OR a.descricao like '%"+palavras[i].toString()+"%'";
        }
        query +=")";
        anuncios = (List<Anuncio>) daoMaster.listaPorQueryModificada(query, map, Anuncio.class);
    }
```

Em questão, se for somente 1 palavra identificada eu estou fazendo uma busca em uma namedQuery já cadastrada no sistema, mais se o sistema identificar mais de uma palavra, estou criando uma query na mão.

No final a query criada foi a seguinte:

```
select a from Anuncio a where a.cidade = :cidade and (a.nome = '%Kelvin' OR a.nome like '%Poket%' OR a.descricao like '%Kelvin%' OR a.descricao like '%Poket%')
```

Alguém pode dar uma olhada e me dizer se há riscos no modo que eu usei? algo como sql inject ou algo do tipo?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Poderia atribuir ao segundo parametro `:nome2` a segunda parte da String do mesmo *atributo*, por exemplo, pegar o segundo **nome** após um espaço.

```
SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nome LIKE :nome OR c.nome LIKE :nome2
```

Alternativa

```
SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nome IN (:nome, :nome2)
```

Na segunda alternativa, o *porcent* `%` não funciona para pegar pedaços da string.

**EDIT**

> Concatenar não é seguro em nenhuma query, o ideal é sempre passar os valores por
>   parametros.

**EDIT2**

> Uma forma limpa e segura de passar a porcentagem `%` no `LIKE` é
>   concatenando direto na query.

Ex:

```
SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nome LIKE CONCAT('%',CONCAT(:nome, '%')) OR c.nome LIKE CONCAT('%',CONCAT(:nome2, '%'))
```

Assim pode passar o valor do parametro diretamente, de forma sucinta sem esse monte de concatenação e gambiarra de Strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Cliente> clientes = sess.createCriteria(Cliente.class)
    .add( Restrictions.in( "nome", palavras ) ).list()
```

Tenta fazer assim. Você faz uma pesquisa usando o *in* no lugar de *or*, que busca todos os valores que você indicou.